# Py2exe, PyQt4 and Postgre Driver (QPSQL)

Tags: python, qt, qt4, pyqt4, py2exe

I`m trying to freeze my application using Py2exe.

My app uses PyQt4 and it apparently works fine with py2exe. But once I`ve uninstalled PyQt, it shows the following error:

QSqlDatabase: QPSQL driver not loaded
QSqlDatabase: available drivers: QPSQL7 QPSQL

Which doesn't make any sense at all. The driver is available, but I can't use it! If PyQt4 is still installed, it works just fine.

This is my py2exe parameters:

```
data_files = [
            ('sqldrivers', [
                'C:\Python26\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\plugins\sqldrivers\qsqlpsql4.dll'
                ])
]

setup(console=["delivery.py"], options={"py2exe" : {"includes" : ["sip", "PyQt4.QtSql", "PyQt4.QtWebKit", "PyQt4.QtNetwork"]}}, data_files=data_files)
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it.

Just copy the file 'libpq.dll' to the application folder and it works like a charm.